# CodeIgniter - Process Simple XML & PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, simplexml

in the controller I have `_send` method. This method returns something like below:

```
 $xmlstr = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes' ?>
<status id="555555555" date="Wed, 28 Mar 2013 12:35:00 +0300">
<id>3806712345671174984921381</id>
<id>3806712345671174984921382</id>
<id>3806712345671174984921383</id>
<id>3806712345671174984921384</id>
<state error="Unknown1">Rejected1</state>
<state error="Unknown2">Rejected2</state>
<state error="">Accepted</state>
<state error="">Accepted</state>
</status>
XML;
```

This method called:

```
$req = $this->_send('bulk',$all_phones,$this->input->post('message'));
```

I am unable to create array or object suitable for passing to model for inserting into DB.
Below what I have now.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);


foreach ($xml as $child) {

                if ($child->getName() == 'id') {
                    $id[] = $child->id;
                }

                if ($child->getName() == 'state') {
                    $state[] = $child;
                    //$state[] = $child['error'];
                }

}

return array_merge($id,$state);
```

I am attempting to achieve something like this array:

```
array(0 => array(
                 'id' => '3806712345671174984921381',
                 'state' => 'Rejected1',
                 'state_error' => 'Unknown1'),
      1 => array( ....
```

Problem with `error` attribute with fault `array_merge`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you *could* do it:

```
// Load XML
$xmlstr = '<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>
<status id="555555555" date="Wed, 28 Mar 2013 12:35:00 +0300">
<id>3806712345671174984921381</id>
<id>3806712345671174984921382</id>
<id>3806712345671174984921383</id>
<id>3806712345671174984921384</id>
<state error="Unknown1">Rejected1</state>
<state error="Unknown2">Rejected2</state>
<state error="">Accepted</state>
<state error="">Accepted</state>
</status>';
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

// Init
$parsed_data = array();

// Parse Id
foreach ($xml->id as $id)
{
    $parsed_data[] = array(
        'id' => (string)$id,
        'state' => '',
        'state_error' => ''
    );
}

// Parse State & State Error
$i = 0;
foreach ($xml->state as $state)
{
    $parsed_data[$i]['state'] = (string)$state;
    $parsed_data[$i]['state_error'] = (string)$state['error'];
    $i++;
}

// Output
var_dump($parsed_data);
```

**Here's the output I got:**

[image]

Comment: One small question. Why do we must use object-to-string conversion by specifying (string)? I was thinking php does it...

Answer (score 2):

You can do write this using a simple `while` statement.

```
$cnt=$xml->id->count();$i=0;
while($i<$cnt)
{
    $new_arr[$i]['id']=(string)$xml->id[$i];
    $new_arr[$i]['state'] = (string)$xml->state[$i];
    $new_arr[$i]['state_error'] = (string)$xml->state[$i]['error'];
    $i++;
}
print_r($new_arr);
```

<kbd>[Demonstration](https://eval.in/141670)</kbd>

Comment: You need to do the casting manually , PHP does not _magically_ do it for you.