# CodeIgniter read/pharse data from url xml

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter

I fallow to:

[CodeIgniter - Process Simple XML & PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23288151/codeigniter-process-simple-xml-php)

I need:

1. on view page paste url to form with xml file.
2. after submit read and parse this xml from url and return result on the same page.

To do This I do:
view

```
<form method='post' action='<?= site_url('home/read_xml') ?>'>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>Name</td>
         <td><input type='text' name='txt_name'></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></td>
       </tr>
    </table>
   </form>
```

function controller:

```
function read_xml(){

   // Check form submit or not
   if($this->input->post('submit') != NULL ){
 
     // POST data
     $postData = $this->input->post();
     $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($postData);

     // Init
$parsed_data = array();

// Parse Id
foreach ($xml->id as $id)
{
    $parsed_data[] = array(
        'id' => (string)$id,
        'state' => '',
        'state_error' => ''
    );
}

// Parse State & State Error
$i = 0;
foreach ($xml->state as $state)
{
    $parsed_data[$i]['state'] = (string)$state;
    $parsed_data[$i]['state_error'] = (string)$state['error'];
    $i++;
}

// Output
var_dump($parsed_data);
 
   }

}
```

But something went wrong:

```
Message: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

Comment: You'd need to read in the contents of the URL first. That'll get you the XML. And just in case: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php

Comment: As the error message has already indicated to you, $postData will be an array of posted data from the form, not a string containing XML or a URL. Perhaps you intended to read a specific value from that post data, instead if the whole array?